# Adding a different value of the same variable to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, bbc-microbit

Using my micro:bit I am trying to add the value of a variable called `sendText` to an array without overwriting its previous stored value for that variable.

```
input.onGesture(Gesture.Shake, () => {
    list.push(sendText)
    binSend = 0
    basic.showString(sendText)
})
```

My array is called list

```
let list: string[] = []
```

I am trying to store single characters in an array then outputting them. If there is a better alternative to using an array I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a value to an array you use `push` function, after, if you need to group the characters pushed to array for output you could to use for your specific example `list.join('')`